# How to run OpenCV scripts via ssh and have output on remote machine display?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ssh

tl;dr: Running OpenCV on Jetson TX2, a la [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvmP0WRVUxI), trying to be able to run the script via ssh from my machine and display on the Jetson's monitor so I dont have to have a keyboard on the Jetson to create, edit, etc.

I am trying to get into developing OpenCV using a Jetson I recently purchased, so I decided to run through Nvidia's tutorials to get a feel for the libraries before I went crazy with them. I started with the tutorial listed above, and it worked successfully when I ran it from the Jetson itself.

Since it would be very inconvenient for me to have to develop directly on the Jetson itself (though not impossible, if that is what I have to do), I wanted to be able to ssh into it, develop code, run it via ssh, then have the output show up on the display connected to the Jetson (which I do have easy access to).

Is this at all possible to do? For reference, my machine is a Windows host running Linux via VirtualBox. Before people tell me to switch to Linux, I would rather not since I already have everything set up on Windows, and there are compatibility issues with some software I am using if I tried to use Linux alone. If I have to run Linux as the host, I can most likely work it out, but I would rather run the virtual machine if at all possible.

I am not sure if this is more suited to the Linux forum (or somewhere else), I asked it here since it is more directly related to OpenCV IMO. But, if that is not the case I will post it there instead.

Many thanks if you are able to help, and if I missed any info you think people would need, please let me know so I can add it to the question.

Comment: Why not use `ssh -X user@jetson` from your Linux box and display on your Linux box? P.S. It may be `ssh -Y user@jetson`

Comment: I would do that, except the display I want it on is not near or connected to my machine, but it is connected to the jetson. I want to do this because I would like to be able to have the jetson elsewhere as it's own unit and be able to deploy to it remotely and have it run whatever code I put on it.

Comment: An idea I had was to use a systemd service and restart it when there is new code i want to run, but I think I would run into the same issue where it would try to run the service on my ssh session instead of on the monitor connected to the jetson.

Comment: @runeguy Did you found any solution for this? I have remotely connected my Jetson device in VS code via ssh and doing all the development in vs code which is good and fast but only problem is if I want to run/debug code, I have to use Jetson.